# Reduce mathjax size using mathjax-grunt-cleaner

Tags: ionic2, mathjax

I am trying to run mathjax into my ionic2 app. Can someone please tell me how to reduce the size of mathjax using mathjax-grunt-cleaner?

Up till now  I have installed grunt using NPM + donwload mathjax latest  + download MathJax-grunt-cleaner from github.

Need help after that.

Comment: You might want to provide more information on what you tried. I admit [the readme](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-grunt-cleaner#mathjax-grunt-cleaner) is a bit sparse and assumes you know grunt a little bit but it's not clear where you are having issues.

Comment: My Grunt knowledge is very-2 basic level. I just want to have small size mathjax setup to be used inside my Ionic2 project. If you can plz help me. I dont know how to run MathJax-grunt-cleaner  in CLI.

Comment: You run a grunt task via `grunt TASKNAME`. There are a couple of example grunt tasks in the file and if those do not fit, then you'll have to write your own task. Deciding which parts remain requires good knowledge of MathJax and more importantly knowing which parts of MathJax your application needs -- the last part is usually the main difficulty but it's something only you can tell, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I needed MathJax for my Ionic 2 Application and I followed the same procedure (grunt-cleaner) as you are following. You can download the resized mathjax folder [here](http://www.filedropper.com/mathjax-grunt-cleaned)
To include it in your Project :

1. Put the extracted folder in your `www` folder.
2. In the src/index.html put this in `head`section:

---

```
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$$','$$'],['$','$'], ['\(','\)']]}});
</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="mathjax/MathJax.js?config=default">
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a pro in Grunt or MatJax but it worked for me like that

```
// download and extract mathjax
curl -J -O https://codeload.github.com/mathjax/MathJax/zip/2.7.8
unzip MathJax-2.7.8.zip
rm MathJax-2.7.8.zip
cd MathJax-2.7.8

// download the grunt file 
curl -J -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mathjax/MathJax-grunt-cleaner/master/Gruntfile.js

// install grunt
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install grunt grunt-contrib-clean grunt-regex-replace --save-dev

// in Gruntfile.js edit the "template" job, or copy it, we wanted to use only html-formulars so i commented out (to keep it)
//"clean:packed"
//"clean:fontTeX"
//"clean:woff"
//"clean:texInput"
//"clean:htmlCssOutput"
//"clean:extensionsTeX"
//"clean:extensionHtmlCss"
//"clean:allConfigs"
//"clean:dropFonts"

It looks like that now:
  grunt.registerTask("template", [
    // **Notes** on the template. When instructions say "Pick one", this means commenting out one item (so that it"s not cleaned).
    //
    //      Early choices.
    "clean:unpacked",
    //"clean:packed", // pick one -- packed for production, unpacked for development.
    //"clean:allConfigs", // if you do not need any combined configuration files.
    //      Fonts. Pick at least one! Check notes above on configurations.
    "clean:fontAsana",
    "clean:fontGyrePagella",
    "clean:fontGyreTermes",
    "clean:fontLatinModern",
    "clean:fontNeoEuler",
    "clean:fontStix",
    "clean:fontStixWeb",
    //"clean:fontTeX",
    //      Font formats. Pick at least one (unless you use SVG output; then clean all).
    //"clean:dropFonts", // when using SVG output
    "clean:eot",
    "clean:otf",
    "clean:png",
    "clean:svg",
    //"clean:woff",
    //      Input. Pick at least one.
    "clean:asciimathInput",
    "clean:mathmlInput",
    //"clean:texInput",
    //       Output
    //"clean:htmlCssOutput",
    "clean:mathmlOutput",
    "clean:svgOutput",
    // Extensions. You probably want to leave the set matching your choices.
    "clean:extensionsAsciimath",
    "clean:extensionsMathml",
    //"clean:extensionsTeX",
    //"clean:extensionHtmlCss",
    // Other items
    "clean:locales",
    "clean:miscConfig",
    //        "clean:miscExtensions", // you probably want that
    "clean:images",
    "clean:notcode"
  ]);

// then run grunt job
grunt template

// clean up
rm -rf node_modules
rm Gruntfile.js
rm package-lock.json
```